# Iframe doen't load content after src changed | Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, appendchild

I am currently writing a `website` that is supposed to run on an `info terminal`.
It has an `<iframe>` showing the content selected from a `menu`.

The menu contains `PDFs` and a `Schedule` for the employees.
The `PDF reader` and the `Schedule` are both on separate HTML documents.
They both work perfectly, but !

My problem occurs when I change the documents src inside the `frame`.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
iframe.src = src_clicked;
```

I am using `pdf.js` to render the PDFs. I render each page on a `<canvas>` and append them all to a `<div>`.
When I start the page with a `PDF`, everything works! But when my `iframe` has had a different src before, it wont append the rendered pages to my container again.

I tried reloading the page inside the iframe like this. But it doesn't do anything.

```js
var ifrm = document.getElementById("iframe");
var iframeDoc = ifrm.contentWindow.document;
ifrm.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

This is how i render the PDF with pdf.js:

```js
PDFJS.getDocument(pageUrl).then(function(pdf) {
        var currentPage = 1;
        var pages = [];
        pdf.getPage(currentPage).then(renderPage);
        function renderPage(page) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            ... //define renderContext
            var renderContext = { ... };
            page.render(renderContext).then(function () {
                if(currentPage < pdf.numPages + 1) {
                    pages[currentPage-1] = canvas;
                    pdf.getPage(currentPage++).then(renderPage);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I don't have any idea what Im doing wrong here.
Please help me

Comment: Can you post the html part of your code?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the iframe and re-append it with the new source? The problem is that different browsers load the iframes differently and you can use the ids to reload it. Something like this : `ifrm.reload("true")`, Have tried something like this before??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it this way:

When displaying a PDF, I remove the iFrame:

```js
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "";

loadPDF(pdfPath);
```

and append the document right onto the `<div>`

When I display a web content again, I append a new iFrame:

```js
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =
         '<iframe id="iframe" type="text/html" src="' + websiteURL + '" ></iframe>';
```

And give it the full size:

```
#iframe{
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```